# reduce jpeg filesize "on the fly" with php

Tags: php, html, jpeg

I would like to lessen the image size (and quality) of a jpeg on the fly when a user is using a certain browser, OS or screen size (used to distinguish mobile from desktop users). How do I do this?
I imagine hat i'd call a script that would return the image e.g.

```
<img src="<?resize.php?file=test.jpg&quality=75?>"
```

and in my resize.php I would need to convert test.jpg to be the *$image* ressource for imagejpeg () with which I can set the image quality.
How do I go about the conversion? also will

```
echo imagejpeg($img,NULL,$quality);
```

result in displaying an image using above html snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write the resizing routine, and then have it saved someone web accessable. And I would cache the file the first time you resize it so you don't have to resize it every time someone loads a page.

Answer (score 1):

Two objections:

- `img` `src` requires an URL, not an image itself (actually, can be a data URL, but that's so wrong especially when trying to compress)
- why rerender images for each hit? That would be horribly slow and inefficient. Just prerender them and select one of the variants according to user's specs.

If you still want to resize on the fly, then have a script `resize.php` or similar that will output the image of the given size. The script has to set the correct `Content-Type` header (`image/jpg`, for your example). Then use this as a tag:

```
<img src="resize.php?file=test.jpg&quality=75">
```

(note: no PHP tags, this is just a link!)